# "Next.js App Requires Node.js Version >= v18.17.0, but Encountering Error with Node.js 16.20.2 - How to Resolve?"

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, installation, frameworks

When i create next js app using cli, an then i type

```
npm run dev
```

I got this error.

```
You are using Node.js 16.20.2. For Next.js, Node.js version >= v18.17.0 is required.
```

But my node version is v20.10.0. How I fix this.

Solve this issue.

```
You are using Node.js 16.20.2. For Next.js, Node.js version >= v18.17.0 is required.
```

Comment: Did you previously install Node at the system level? I am guessing you might have, and that's what next is picking up.

Look for `system` in your nvm list and see if that matches. If it does then you can uninstall it and try again, but do so in a new terminal to ensure your PATH is updated.

Either way, the core of the issue here is your PATH order. Next is picking up Node from the first location it finds it, so to troubleshoot, you'll want to find out where that location is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your Node.js installation to a version that meets or exceeds the required version (18.17.0). You can use a version manager like NVM (Node Version Manager) to easily switch between Node.js versions. Here are the steps to update using NVM:

- nvm install 18.17.0
- nvm use 18.17.0

then;

- npm install again
- and npm run dev

Comment: Yes, this worked. nvm install 18.17.0, nvm use 18.17.0, npm install again, npm run dev

Comment: Great. Although it would be best if it is installed globally and not just in your individual project

Answer (score 1):

You can install the latest version of Node using this command:

```
nvm install node --latest-npm
```

after running this command, re run the dev server by `npm run dev` and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Debian, the Node.JS package on their repo is outdated. You need to uninstall it and install it from the [Nodesource repos](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions). Also make sure the right node version is in your $PATH variable.

Comment: Wouldn't use of NVM be better for just about any developer on just about any platform?

Answer (score 0):

The best simple steps for WINDOWS user are here..
You can download the 'nvm-setup.exe' from https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases/download/1.1.12/nvm-setup.exe and install it.

1. after the installation close all open terminals and reopen again;
2. Go to the terminal and check nvm version - it will show the
   current version
3. Install the latest by writing in the terminal:

   - nvm install latest
4. Final Step, use the latest version you downloaded..
   nvm use "last version'
   for me the version was 21.7.1
   I used it:
   nvm use 21.7.1
   PS C:\Users\H P> nvm use 21.7.1
   Now using node v21.7.1 (64-bit)
   Everything worked perfectly !!

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation. I solved it by installing pnpm. It seems to be an npm issue.