Next.js error: "You are using Node.js 18.15.0. For Next.js, Node.js version >= 18.17.0 is required" despite using a higher Node.js version
I recently created a Next.js app using the CLI, and when I tried to run the development server with npm run dev, I encountered this error:
You are using Node.js 18.15.0. For Next.js, Node.js version >= 18.17.0 is required.

However, my actual Node.js version is 20.10.0, which is clearly higher than the required version.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Verified my Node.js version with node -v: v20.10.0
Checked nvm list: showing v22.5.1 and system Node.js versions.

I’m not sure why Next.js is picking up an older version of Node.js. How do I fix this?

This Q/A is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77772200/next-js-app-requires-node-js-version-v18-17-0-but-encountering-error-with-n

You need to check the node version in the same command prompt.
For example if you are getting the error in vs code terminal you need to check the node version in the vs code terminal as well.


Verify Node.js versions:
Check available versions here to ensure you are using a compatible version for your Next.js project.

Install and use the correct version with nvm: Using nvm allows you to switch between Node.js versions easily, ensuring compatibility with different projects. Run the following commands to install and use the correct version:
nvm install 22.5.1
nvm use 22.5.1


Re-run your development server:
After switching versions, run your project again:
npm run dev




sample image



I Think that there is Two Node versions on you machine you could try to list all node versions
npm -g ls
Alternatively you could uninstall npm and make sure no npm on your machine then install it again
versions
npm -g rm
Then install it again
